# Why wouldn't this star-counting code work?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, counting

I tried to count the stars(ratings) of each rating column in this URL 'https://seedly.sg/reviews/p2p-lending/funding-societies'

I use selenium to automate the whole process.
but neither stars, star_count, nor star_count_list has any content in it. 
The code makes logical sense to me and seems fine, may i know what's the problems in my code?

Thanks in advance.

```
##These are basic setups
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd

'''Create new instance of Chrome in Incognito mode'''
##Adding the incognito argument to our webdriver
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(" — incognito")
##create a new instance of Chrome
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/w97802/chromedriver')

'''Scrape Basic Info'''
from parsel import Selector
url = 'https://seedly.sg/reviews/p2p-lending/funding-societies'
browser.get(url)
selector = Selector(text=browser.page_source)

####################################################################
##This is the star-count code
'''Count stars simple'''
star_count_list = []

ratingcolumn = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"qr0ren-7 euifNX")]')
for rows in ratingcolumn:
    star_count = 0
    stars = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//svg[contains(@stroke,"57CF8D")]')
    for numofstars in range(0,len(stars)):
        star_count += 1
        star_count_list.append(star_count)

print(stars)
print(star_count)
'''Print Stars Result''' 
for i,e in enumerate(star_count_list, start=1):
        print ('\n \n \n ' + str(i) + '. \n', e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you code id perfect buttThe way you are trying to locate an svg element is not correct.

You need to replace xpath

```
//svg[contains(@stroke,"57CF8D")]
```

with

```
//*[local-name() = 'svg'][contains(@stroke,'57CF8D')]
```

I'm curious how did you populate such xpath. I've tested in chrome and it doesn't show any finding. Better way to populate in chrome once for surety.

As an alternative you can use css selector to locate the same element

```
div[class='qr0ren-7 euifNX'] svg[stroke='#57CF8D']
```

in you code:

```
stars = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='qr0ren-7 euifNX'] svg[stroke='#57CF8D']")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried to specify the path: browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="qr0ren-7 euifNX"]/span/span/svg[contains(@stroke,"#57CF8D")'), but it doesn't work. I don't quite understand why, because I followed each dropdown menu to specify the path. The path specification before svg tag is still fine. May I know why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: SVG mainly used for vector type diagrams like bar charts, pie charts, scalable icons, scalable logos and other design diagrams. SVG viewer is used to render the elements.Usually SVG elements are not captured by the selenium. https://medium.com/@sajithatharaka/automating-svg-elements-with-selenium-a7c31f99ebf8

Comment: i see! i used the code you provided and turned out finding in fact the colour code is not what distinguishes the coloured-star and non-coloured-star. The colour codes are the same but the non-coloured-star's width is 0%

Comment: and therefore i derived the code: browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="qr0ren-7 euifNX"]/span/span/span[contains(@style,"width:100%")') but it said invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression. I wonder why? Because I checked it for each drop down menu and it should be correct? Thanks!

Comment: its invalid because you missed `]` valid is `//div[@class="qr0ren-7 euifNX"]/span/span/span[contains(@style,"width:100%")]` .in your code `browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='qr0ren-7 euifNX']/span/span/span[contains(@style,'width:100%')]")`. I would suggest, go through some tutorial to learn in detail about create and populate xpath. if answer is helpful then access it and upvote. if you have other questions then post separate question. Thanks

Comment: i see! sure! thanks a lot for your help! wish you an awesome year ahead!